# Assistance building correct multi-level polymorphic data structure

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

I am struggling with my data structures for a storage application.  Consider the issue equivalent in terms of a private library that doesn’t use public library techniques.

- A book is stored in a row on a shelf.
- When a book is checked out, it is owned by the patron.
- When a book is returned, I need to know where it should be stored by row and shelf.

I need to track the book so that I know that, if it is stored, where it is stored and, if it is checked out, who has it and what to do with it when it is returned.  How I see it is as follows:

```
Book
has_one :location
has_one :patron, through: :location, source: :library, source_type: 'Patron'
has_one :row, through: :location, source: :library, source_type: 'Row'

Location
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :library, polymorphic: true

Patron
has_many :locations, as: :library
has_many :books, through: :locations

Row
has_many :locations, as: :library
has_many :books, through: :locations
```

I had already built the structure to this point only I had some has_many/belongs_to relationships turned backward which caused my nested forms to fail.  I am trying to make sure I get it right this time.  This appears okay to me as far as it goes.  Is it?

However, it only goes down to rows and I need to identify shelves within rows.  I’m at kind of a loss of how to build that data structure.  I think that the shelf relationship with location must be polymorphic but that the row and shelf relationship can be direct.  Does that make sense?  **I am unsure as to whether it is correct because location seems to be a shelf, not a shelf within a row.**  I am looking at the following:

```
Book
has_one :location
has_one :patron, through: :location, source: :library, source_type: 'Patron'
has_one :shelf, through: :location, source: :library, source_type: 'Shelf'

Location
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :library, polymorphic: true

Patron
has_many :locations, as: :library
has_many :books, through: :locations

Shelf
has_many :locations, as: :library
has_many :books, through: :locations
belongs_to :row

Row
has_many :shelves
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution presented in the question is working as designed.  There is an issue regarding sorting on the foreign polymorphic columns, such as sorting the books by location, but that seems to be just an expected outcome. See question and answers to [24001705](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001705/how-do-i-sort-a-foreign-column-using-datatable-will-paginate-as-in-railscast-3) if you are interested.